# Smart Contracts - Chainlink VRF / @openzeppelin/truffle-upgrades compatibility

Tags: random, numbers, solidity, truffle, chainlink

Right now i am transforming a basic smart contract into a upgradeable smart contract using [@openzeppelin/truffle-upgrades](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@openzeppelin/truffle-upgrades)

So i followed all required steps from the docs but one issue remains:

Truffle-Upgrades requires me to replace the constructor with an initializer which is fine for me, but not for the smart contracts imported into my own smart contract, sample:

```
pragma solidity 0.6.6;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/VRFConsumerBase.sol";

contract Sample is VRFConsumerBase {
    
    address private owner;
    
    bytes32 internal keyHash;
    uint256 internal fee;
    
    constructor(address _owner)
        VRFConsumerBase(
            0xa555fC018435bef5A13C6c6870a9d4C11DEC329C, // VRF Coordinator
            0x84b9B910527Ad5C03A9Ca831909E21e236EA7b06  // LINK Token
        ) public
    {
        keyHash = 0xcaf3c3727e033261d383b315559476f48034c13b18f8cafed4d871abe5049186;
        fee = 0.1 * 10 ** 18; // 0.1 LINK (Varies by network)
        
        owner = _owner;
    }

    ...
```

And therefore truffle complains:

```
../@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/VRFConsumerBase.sol:182: Contract `VRFConsumerBase` has a constructor
Define an initializer instead
```

As it is a third party package i can not replace it :)

Are there any architectural tricks/configurations?

I went through pretty much all docs on chainlink/truffle but did not find a solution for this issue.

Thanks!

**UPDATE 1:**

First of all, i modified the VRFConsumerBase contract to: (i also removed the comments to keep it short..)

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.6.12;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/vendor/SafeMathChainlink.sol";

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/interfaces/LinkTokenInterface.sol";

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/VRFRequestIDBase.sol";

abstract contract VRFConsumerBaseUpgradable is VRFRequestIDBase {

  using SafeMathChainlink for uint256;

  function fulfillRandomness(bytes32 requestId, uint256 randomness)
    internal virtual;

  function requestRandomness(bytes32 _keyHash, uint256 _fee, uint256 _seed)
    internal returns (bytes32 requestId)
  {
    LINK.transferAndCall(vrfCoordinator, _fee, abi.encode(_keyHash, _seed));
    
    uint256 vRFSeed  = makeVRFInputSeed(_keyHash, _seed, address(this), nonces[_keyHash]);
    
    nonces[_keyHash] = nonces[_keyHash].add(1);
    return makeRequestId(_keyHash, vRFSeed);
  }

  // removed immutable keyword <--
  LinkTokenInterface internal LINK;
  // removed immutable keyword <--
  address private vrfCoordinator;

  mapping(bytes32 /* keyHash */ => uint256 /* nonce */) private nonces;

  // replaced constructor with initializer <--
  function initialize(address _vrfCoordinator, address _link) public {
    vrfCoordinator = _vrfCoordinator;
    LINK = LinkTokenInterface(_link);
  }

  function rawFulfillRandomness(bytes32 requestId, uint256 randomness) external {
    require(msg.sender == vrfCoordinator, "Only VRFCoordinator can fulfill");
    fulfillRandomness(requestId, randomness);
  }

}
```

What did i do:

- I replaced the constructor with an initializer
- I removed the immutable keyword from the state variables

Next, i used the Initializable contract from @openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable in my file system to prevent the smart contract executing the initializer more than once:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.6.12;

abstract contract Initializable {

    bool private _initialized;

    bool private _initializing;

    modifier initializer() {
        require(_initializing || !_initialized, "Initializable: contract is already initialized");

        bool isTopLevelCall = !_initializing;
        if (isTopLevelCall) {
            _initializing = true;
            _initialized = true;
        }

        _;

        if (isTopLevelCall) {
            _initializing = false;
        }
    }
}
```

**Important:**

I did not import the Initializable contract via the import statement in solidity.

Instead i copied the source code manually and set the compiler to 0.6.12 because @openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/proxy/utils/Initializable.sol is running on 0.8.x

Finally, i updated my contract to implement the Initializable and the new VRFConsumerBaseUpgradable contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.6.12;

import "./Initializable.sol";
import "./VRFConsumerBaseUpgradable.sol";

contract Sample is Initializable, VRFConsumerBaseUpgradable {

    bytes32 internal keyHash;
    uint256 internal fee;
    
    address private owner;
    
    function initialize(address _owner)
        public
        initializer
    {
        VRFConsumerBaseUpgradable.initialize(
            0xa555fC018435bef5A13C6c6870a9d4C11DEC329C, // VRF Coordinator
            0x84b9B910527Ad5C03A9Ca831909E21e236EA7b06  // LINK Token
        );

        keyHash = 0xcaf3c3727e033261d383b315559476f48034c13b18f8cafed4d871abe5049186;
        fee = 0.1 * 10 ** 18; 
        
        owner = _owner;
    }

    function getRandomNumber(uint256 userProvidedSeed) public returns (bytes32 requestId) {
        require(LINK.balanceOf(address(this)) >= fee, "Not enough LINK - fill contract with faucet");
        return requestRandomness(keyHash, fee, userProvidedSeed);
    }

    function fulfillRandomness(bytes32 requestId, uint256 randomness) internal override {
        // logic
    }

    ...
    
}
```

I tested an initial migration as well as an upgrade via truffle and it both worked so i think this is fine and i am leaving this for future researchers..

What do you think? Should i create a merge request for VRFConsumerBaseUpgradable?

Comment: Great question. The answer might be a little technical. You could have your constructor be called and just have blanks for those two variables, and then have your initializer actually set them. 

Is there a way to override truffle looking at the constructor? If not, we could add that to the plugin.

Comment: Thank you for for your answer @PatrickCollins. Unfortunately truffle requires me to remove the constructor completely... I also can not override truffle core logic as there is some more logic depending on it. What do you mean by saying *you could add that to the plugin* ?

Comment: I was saying you could upgrade the upgrades plug-in to allow modifiers. The other thing you could do (this might be easier) is use your own custom vrfconsumerbase. With this, you just have an initializer function instead of a constructor. Do you know how to do that? Just copy the code of the vrfconsumerbase into your code and modify it

Comment: Alright, thanks for the update. I will work on the codebase and update the question with the new version of my smart contract / VRFConsumerBase / Initializable

Comment: @PatrickCollins i updated the source code and created a new VRFConsumerBaseUpgradable.. what do you think about this approach?
Basically developers can now upgrade their smart contracts when using chainlink.

Comment: I think this is the correct approach to take. Sorry on not getting back here. Is this something that you'd want to introduce to the chainlink repo? Or answer here below?

Comment: I have added this file here - https://gist.github.com/abhi3700/a3030c64b432c793c3899aee4ffd8ad0

Comment: How to use the subscription id and all the different parameters that are required by the VRFCoordinator interface? Could you provide an example of a working solution for fulfillRandomness and getRandomNumber?
I really don't get it since I can't see how to link a consumer to the new VRFConsumerBaseUpgradable contract.
Thanks